# How to use opengl textures correct?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong with the textures. The idea was to give different textures(.bmp) to cubes. The program is running without problems, but the textures are not shown correctly.

Here is my texture-loader :

```
GLuint LoadTexture( const char * filename )
{

  GLuint texture;
  int width, height;
  unsigned char * data;
  FILE * file;
  file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
  if ( file == NULL ) return 0;
  width = 1024;
  height = 512;
  data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3 );

  fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
  fclose( file );

  for(int i = 0; i < width * height ; ++i)
  {
      int index = i*3;
      unsigned char B,R;
      B = data[index];
      R = data[index+2];

      data[index] = R;
      data[index+2] = B;

   }
   glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
   glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
   glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE );
   glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );

   glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );
   glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT );
   glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT );
   gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );
   free( data );

    return texture;
}
```

My cube-function:

```
 static void drawBox(GLfloat size, GLenum type)
 {
   static GLfloat n[6][3] =
   {
     {-1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
     {0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
     {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
     {0.0, -1.0, 0.0},
     {0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
     {0.0, 0.0, -1.0}
   };
   static GLint faces[6][4] =
   {
      {0, 1, 2, 3},
      {3, 2, 6, 7},
      {7, 6, 5, 4},
      {4, 5, 1, 0},
      {5, 6, 2, 1},
      {7, 4, 0, 3}
   };
   GLfloat v[8][3];
   GLint i;

   v[0][0] = v[1][0] = v[2][0] = v[3][0] = -size / 2;
   v[4][0] = v[5][0] = v[6][0] = v[7][0] = size / 2;
   v[0][1] = v[1][1] = v[4][1] = v[5][1] = -size / 2;
   v[2][1] = v[3][1] = v[6][1] = v[7][1] = size / 2;
   v[0][2] = v[3][2] = v[4][2] = v[7][2] = -size / 2;
   v[1][2] = v[2][2] = v[5][2] = v[6][2] = size / 2;

   for (i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
      glBegin(type);
      glNormal3fv(&n[i][0]);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][0]][0]);
      glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][1]][0]);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
      glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][2]][0]);
      glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3fv(&v[faces[i][3]][0]);
      glEnd();
  }
}
```

drawing the cubes:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
texture= LoadTexture( "texture.bmp" );
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
solidCube(1);
```

Comment: You are not specifying any texture coordinates for your vertices.

Comment: @rkapl: OP is using texture coordinate generation. Even with the default settings it should generate *some* texture coordinates, but they'll likely not match for a cube.

Comment: Thank you, I have missed that one.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. So I need to add texture coordinates to my Cube-funktion?

Comment: I tried to add texture coordinates but it is still not working. I edited the changes in my question

Comment: Is your file a standard windows bitmap file?  That isn't just raw pixel data; it has a 54-byte header that you'll need to read to figure out where to start reading pixels.

Comment: @conci: Can you elaborte on what "he textures are not shown correctly" means? Do you just get a black or white cube? Or the same color all over? Or some weird pixel mess? Or soemthing else?